# Row versioning in NoSQL database

Tags: cassandra, nosql, bigdata

I am in the process of designing a data model for a specific use case.
Consider the following columns:

- Row ID
- Row Version
- Value

The access pattern is that a Spark writer will append these rows into a database and a non-Spark reader will access them searching by the `Value` for example `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Value=1`, these reads will happen from an online application and not a Big Data framework, so time is of the essence here.

Since this is a very large dataset, I am looking at Big Data solutions, specifically I was considering Cassandra for this use case.
However, I am having trouble figuring out how I can model the data in an effective way.

Since Cassandra supports upserts, I originally thought of using the `Row ID` as the partition key and dropping the `Row Version` altogether.
However, even with indices, I would expect poor read performance since the reads do not use the partition key.

The issue is, that each `Row ID` can appear multiple times with different `Value` but I want to only consider the specific row a good result for a specific query if `Value` matches the queried one AND it is the latest version of the row.

My other ideas included a helper table which is partitioned by `Row ID` and holds the latest `Row Version` for every row. However, this join is not something which, I believe, a reader can handle. The other option would be to query each `Row ID` specifically, but that would generate tens of thousands of queries for every request

Looking for ideas on how to model the data or which tools (databases, frameworks..) can be used to create such an application.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In Cassandra, the first rule of data modelling is to design one table for each of application query. In your case the app query is "get the record where some value is equal to X".

The schema for this query would be:

```
CREATE TABLE values (
    value text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (value)
)
```

Regardless of how large the dataset is, retrieving partitions would be quick:

```
SELECT ... FROM values WHERE value = ?
```

For what it's worth, it's not necessary to use an artificial ID for tables. It's a lot better to use natural keys like email addresses since you already have those in your data.

Also, all mutations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and upserts included) contain a timestamp so only the latest version of the partition/row/column is returned by Cassandra so you don't need to implement some sort of versioning. Cheers!

Comment: The issue is that if I model my data like this  for example:
```CREATE TABLE values (
    value text,
    email text,
    version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (value)
)```

and then insert the following rows into the table:
```("value1", "id1", 1), ("value2", "id1", 2)```

If I query by value `SELECT ... FROM values WHERE value='value1'` I expect an empty result, because `id1` appears in a different partition with a higher version.

Now I understand that might be a problem because they are not in the same partition to be deduplicated, and that's my problem exactly.

Comment: For the sake of argument you can drop the `version` column and just say that I want the latest `id1` to be accounted for.